# Waiting for ID to change on component using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, puppeteer

I have a table component that has pagination. I've added a data attribute on the `<tbody>` tag that changes when clicking the table page next button (e.g. `data-id: table-page-one` changes to `data-id: table-page-two`. I need to wait for this ID to chance before checking the row elements. The test is passing if I run it with `SLOMO=true HEADLESS=false`, but when I run it normally, after the pagination click, It gives the following error: `thrown: Exceeded timeout of 20000 ms for a test`. My code is similar to the follow:

```
if ('verify table row checkboxes are checked', async () => {
  await page.click(nextTablePageSelector);

  // gets stuck here
  await page. waitForSelector("[data-id='table-page-two']");

  // below works in SLOMO=true HEADLESS=false mode
  // checking each row using $$eval
});
```

I've with a custom delay method between the `page.click` and `page.waitForSelector` and it works, but the team doesn't want to uses delays, because it can lead to flakey tests.

What is the proper way to watch for part of the UI changing, or more specifically, watching for an attribute that you're already used to change?

Comment: Consider posting a test page somewhere. The community can then better assist and debug more predictably.

Comment: Could you recommend an environment for that?

Comment: Perhaps a minimal reproduction on [Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/)? We could then test the resulting HTML directly by using the embedded iFrame URL. For example: [source](https://codepen.io/anthumchris/pen/vYYPYwj) => [testable result](https://cdpn.io/anthumchris/fullpage/vYYPYwj)

Answer (score 0):

Consider grouping the promises and using the `visible` flag.

```
await Promise.all([
  page.click(nextTablePageSelector),
  page.waitForSelector('tbody[data-id=page-two]', { visible: true }),
])
```

Comment: I implemented the code above. Same issue. It passes in `SLOMO=true HEADLESS=false` mode, but fails with the same error otherwise.

Comment: Can you share the URL of the paginated page you're testing against?

Comment: I cannot, unfortunately. It's just a MUI 4 table.

Comment: I confirmed through the elements tab in dev tools that the id attribute that I added to the tbody tag successfully changes when the next page button is clicked.